# QGIS .adf file saved as GTiff changes elevations

Tags: qgis, dem, geotiff-tiff, elevation, raster-conversion

I have got two .adf DEMs which I need in GTiff format so they can be merged. When I 'Save As' the layer as a GTiff, the resulting output has elevations which are inconsistent with the original .adf file. For example: the max elevation in the first .adf file is 2943.76 m and the same file converted to GTiff format has a max elevation of 2881.86 m.
Where is this discrepancy coming from and how can I ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: How did you check the min/max values? For a comparison you can use Raster > Miscellaneous > Info to check both raster.

Comment: Min/max values checked using the histogram. Also important to note the histogram looks wildly different (much smoother) on the GTiff in comparison to original .adf file.

Comment: Do they have different resolutions? Maybe you 'Save As' the .adf with a different resolution. This could be the reason for a 'smoother' histogram.

Comment: In QGIS the 'Save As' resolution defaults to the resolution of the original file, in my case 5m. I have therefore been using 5m as the export resolution.

Comment: load the .adf and the converted .tif and use the raster calculator to compute the difference. Is there any? If so, is it enlightening?